# How to remove unwanted characters from a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I am inserting thousand of rows in a table in **MySQL** in **UTF8 encoding**, *varchar(255)*. I check if the row is previously inserted by using the operator = . I have seen many duplicate entries.  When I "clean" the strings with PHP I find that the number of duplicate entries reduces, the maximum reduction (minimum of entries) being if I only accept *non-extended ASCII*, which is very limited (in this case I suspect that I am interpreting 2 genuinely different strings as if they were the same).

How can I delete unwanted characters (*\n, \t, etc.*) which can difficult the " = " comparison without distorting the data or restricting too much (non-extended ASCII is not accepted, as we are in UTF8).

Comment: how about using a `REPLACE` query instead of checking previous inserts ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The problem I had is that the text was way too long, and varchar(255) limited the result. I have tested with REPLACE and with "=" and it works the same now. In any case, I have always had some reluctance to use **REPLACE**, something I read about its performance or something. Thanks!

Comment: yw, replace has its flaws but it's meant for this kind of use case. As a rule of thumb, always delegate all data handling tasks to the database whenever possible.